# How to "Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains)"

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am trying a maven clean install but get an error saying it can’t locate my Pom.xml

Then I tried “mvn archetypes:generate” and then I get asked some set of questions which I don’t know the default value to

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Mambo :)

you dont need to generate a pom.xml via mvn archetypes:generate - you can edit it by hand in an editor (IDEA, notepad, etc).

Here is a minimal pom, which I copied from the documentation below. And please note the small 'p', its pom.xml, not Pom.xml

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you. Finally working. 

Lol, yeah pom.xml